# Принцип ударений в словах с одной гласной

Tags: фонетика

Возвращаясь к вопросу об ударении в слове "пост".
Есть ли какая-то закономерность постановки ударения в таких односложных словах? Потому что, например, *клад-клАдов, фрукт-фрУктов, плод-плодОв, гроб-гробОв*, но совсем аналогичное *сноб-снОбов*.

Comment: Закономерности наверняка есть. Посмотрите словарь Зализняка. И потом нам расскажите! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начнем с того, что вопрос поставлен не совсем правильно. Количество слогов в слове здесь второстепенный показатель. Подобному смешению ударений при формообразовании подвержены слова без суффиксов флексий И.п., у которых ударение падает на **первый** слог, и только в трех- и более сложных словах - изредка на второй.

Для слов среднего и женского рода - свои закономерности. И свои - для слов с суффиксами, в ом числе и непродуктивными (типа "хомяк", "вратарь"). Отдельный разговор про слова с беглой гласной ("лев").

Единого закона нет, как уже тут говорилось, тенденция в языке сравнительно новая. есть некие статистические закономерности, которые показывают, что подобное смещение, со всеми вышеперечисленными оговорками)  чаще проявляется у слов более современных или осовремененных. КУ слов же исконно русских ударение на флексию переходит только тогда, когда это обусловлено историческими причинами.
Но, увы, это всего лишь закономерности. 
Кстати, в оценке нормативности которых словари часто расходятся.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько помню старая норма произношения предполагала в подобных слов ударение исключительно на корень слова *доехали до мОста, много пОртов* и пр. Современная тенденция смещать ударение на окончание. Так как тенденция эта сравнительно недавняя, то орфоэпическая норма ещё не устаканилась и от словаря к словарю варьируется довольно сильно.
Чем, например, отличается "мост" от "торта" сказать сложно, но в первом случае словарь Зарвы рекомендует "мостЫ", а во втором - подчёркивает, что **не** *тортЫ, а тОрты*.

В общем, нужно или за каждым отдельным словом лезть в словарь, или говорить как считаете правильным вы сами.